# Linq Find all items in collection from an other collection

Tags: c#, linq, collections, find, contain

I've an enum collection

```
    List<MyEnum> myEnums = new List<MyEnum>{MyEnum.Item1, MyEnum.Item2}
```

I've a object collection

```
List<MyObject> myObjects = MyObjects.GetMyObjects ();
```

MyObject have a property that is a list of MyEnum

```
myObjects[0].MyEnums  /* contain {MyEnum.Item1, MyEnum.Item5, MyEnum.Item6} */
```

I would like to find all myObjects which property myObject.MyEnums contain MyEnum.Item1 or MyEnum.Item2 (myEnums).
Thks

Comment: What did you try?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this: 
`myObjects.Where(m => m.MyEnums.Intersect(myEnums).Any())`;

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApplication2
{
    public class Program
    {
        public enum MyEnum { Item1, Item2, Item3 }
        public class MyObject
        {
            public List<MyEnum> myEnums;
            public MyObject(List<MyEnum> myEnums)
            {
                this.myEnums = myEnums;
            }
        }


        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<MyEnum> myEnums1 = new List<MyEnum> { MyEnum.Item1, MyEnum.Item2 };
            List<MyEnum> myEnums2 = new List<MyEnum> { MyEnum.Item1 };
            List<MyEnum> myEnums3 = new List<MyEnum> { MyEnum.Item3 };

            List<MyObject> myObjects = new List<MyObject>();

            myObjects.Add(new MyObject(myEnums1));
            myObjects.Add(new MyObject(myEnums2));
            myObjects.Add(new MyObject(myEnums3));



            List<MyEnum> myEnumsFind = new List<MyEnum> { MyEnum.Item1, MyEnum.Item2 };

            var result = myObjects.Where(x => myEnumsFind.Any(y => x.myEnums.Contains(y))).ToList();

        }
    }
}
```